# Does Serilog support syslog protocol

Tags: serilog

Is there a syslog sink for Serilog?

I'm trying to make Serilog work with Logstash, but keep the freedom to easily switch to another aggregator, without config changes in my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like now we have an implementation:

https://github.com/vermeeca/Serilog.Sinks.Syslog/tree/master

Comment: There is now also https://github.com/IonxSolutions/serilog-sinks-syslog, which is more fully featured, and supported on .NET Core (the one you posted isn't). Disclaimer: I'm the author

Answer (score 3):

What I do for this scenario is I use the RollingFileSink with the JsonFormatter, and then use nxlog to  ship the logs to my syslog server.

Answer (score 1):

No, none that I'm aware of, but it's definitely something that would be welcomed as a contribution. If you'd like to pursue writing one please feel free to reach out on the mailing list for help.